# how java project utilize wavm(web assembly virtual machine)?

Tags: java, webassembly, eos

guys
as you known ,WAVM(web assembly virtual machine) is a known wasm vm, and it is easy to integrate with c++ project , but I write java project ,I would like to run wavm in my java project and utilize wasm to load and run functions in wasm.
I don't get good solution by google search, anyone know easy or viable way to integrate with java project and call related method in java? 
Thanks in advance !